# Dojo Exception on hiding a dijit.Dialog

Tags: dojo, dijit.form

I have a Dialog with a form inside. The following code is just an example of what I'm trying to do. When you close a dijit.Dialog, if you dont't destroy recursively his children, you just can't reopen it (with the same id).

If you don't want to destroy your widget you can do something like that :

```
var createDialog = function(){
    try{
    // try to show the hidden dialog
        var dlg = dijit.byId('yourDialogId');
        dlg.show();
    } catch (err) {
    // create the dialog
        var btnClose = new dijit.form.Button({
           label:'Close',
           onClick: function(){
               dialog.hide();
           }
        }, document.createElement("button"));
        var dialog = new dijit.Dialog({
           id:'yourDialogId',
           title:'yourTitle',
           content:btnClose
        });
        dialog.show();
    }
}
```

I hope this can help but with this code the error thrown is :

```
exception in animation handler for: onEnd (_base/fx.js:153)

Type Error: Cannot call method 'callback' of undefined (_base/fx.js:154)
```

I have to say I'm a little lost with this one ! It is driving me crazy ^^

PS : sorry for my "French" English ^^

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll introduce you to your new best friend: `dojo.hitch()`

This allows you to bind your `onClick` function to the context in which it was created. Chances are, when you push the button in your code, it is calling your `.show()` `.hide()` form the context of the global window.  `var dlg` was bound to your `createDialog` function, so it's insides are not visible to the global window, so the global window sees this as `undefined`.

Here's an example of what I changed to your code:

```
var createDialog = function(){

    // try to show the hidden dialog
    var dlg = dijit.byId('yourDialogId');
    dlg.show();

    // create the dialog
    var btnClose = new dijit.form.Button({
        label:'Close',
        onClick: function(){
            dojo.hitch(this, dlg.hide());
        }
    }, document.createElement("button"));
    dlg.domNode.appendChild(btnClose.domNode);
    var btnShow = new dijit.form.Button({
        label : 'Open',
        onClick : function() {
            dojo.hitch(this, dlg.show());
        }
    }, document.createElement("Button"));
    dojo.body().appendChild(btnShow.domNode);
};  

dojo.ready(function() {
    createDialog();
});
```

Note the use of `dojo.hitch()` to bind any future calls or clicks of the various buttons to the context in which the `dlg` was created, forever granting the button's `onclick` method access to the inside of the `createDialog` function, where `var dlg` exists.

Answer (score 0):

hi if i understand correctly, you didn't need to destroy dijit.Dialog every time. E.g.:

HTML: define simple button:

```
<button id="buttonTwo" dojotype="dijit.form.Button" onclick="showDialog();" type="button">
   Show me!
</button>
```

Javascript:

```
// required 'namespaces'
dojo.require("dijit.form.Button");
dojo.require("dijit.Dialog");

// creating dialog
var secondDlg;
dojo.addOnLoad(function () {
        // define dialog content
        var content = new dijit.form.Button({
                    label: 'close',
                    onClick: function () {
                              dijit.byId('formDialog').hide();
                             }
            });

     // create the dialog:
         secondDlg = new dijit.Dialog({
                id: 'formDialog',
                title: "Programatic Dialog Creation",
                style: "width: 300px",
                content: content
            });
        });

          function showDialog() {
            secondDlg.show();
         }
```

See [Example](http://pastehtml.com/view/1dyzss7.html) and reed about [dijit.dialog](http://docs.dojocampus.org/dijit/Dialog)

Comment: I'm aware of this syntax but that's not what I'm looking for.
Is someone can tell me what's wrong in my code ?

PS : dojoType is deprecated, you should use data-dojo-type now, HTML5 is growing.

Comment: There are no errors in code that you provided. It is working (http://pastehtml.com/view/1dz0jne.html), possible there is error in other parts of the code...  Could you please provide a bit more code?