# Show and hide dijit popup using dojo

Tags: dojo

I have created a diji dialog using:

```
<div id="popup" data-dojo-type="dijit.dialog" data-dojo-props="style:'width:350px;top:25px;display:none'"></div>
```

I am then showing the popup using

```
popup.show();
```

On the popup is a cancel button that should close the popup:

```
dojo.on(dojo.dom.byId("cancel"), "click", closePopup());

function closePopup(){
    popup.hide();
}
```

It closes it, but after closing it once and reopening and closing it I am getting the following errors:

```
exception in animation handler for: onEnd
TypeError: cannot read calback property of undefined
```

I have searched for a solution, and I believe it's something to do with the dojo.on method and disconnecting it?

Any help or advice would be fantastic, thank you.

EDIT

I have tried this:

```
function closePopup(){
    dojo.hitch(dojo.dom.byId("cancel"), baselinePopup.hide());
}
```

This works:

```
require(["dojo/on", "dojo/_base/window"], function(on, win){
  var signal = on(win.doc, "click", function(){
    // remove listener after first event
    signal.remove();
    // do something else...
  });
});
```

Comment: Here are two links ( [link1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12679110/dojo-dialog-onend-animation-exception) and [link2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5577096/dojo-exception-on-hiding-a-dijit-dialog)) that relates to your problem

Comment: @frank I can't seem to get it to work, see updated question.

Comment: Here another [link](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.7/dijit/Dialog.html#forms-and-functionality-in-dialogs) for opening and closing dialog with a button **inside** the dialog.

Answer (score 0):

```
require(["dojo/on", "dojo/_base/window"], function(on, win){
  var signal = on(win.doc, "click", function(){
    // remove listener after first event
    signal.remove();
    // do something else...
  });
});
```